# Any way to use Parse.Query as parameter for cloud function?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm guessing this is a dumb question, but is there a way to call a Parse Cloud Code function, using a Query object as a parameter? For example...

```
   myQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("myClass");
   //do some query setup...
   parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
   parameters.put("query", myQuery);
   ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("queryFunction", parameters, new FunctionCallback() {
     public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
       //do something with return object
     }
   }
```

In trying this so far, it seems Parse Objects can't be sent as parameters, and Queries don't seem to fare any better.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the query itself.  You could create a JSON object to represent the query, similar to how it would be formatted on the cloud in javascript, but that may be a lot of work.  It may be a better idea to instead format your parameters like this:

```
{ className: <class name to query>,
  equalTo: [ param1:value,
             param2:value...
           ],
  notEqualTo: ...,
  sort:...,
  ....
}
```

Then construct the query on the backend. You could also instead pass in the parameters that you use to determine how to set up the query.

Comment: That's what I figured it would have to be. Well, I'll see if I can deal with that :-)

Comment: Care to explain why you want to pass a query to the server? If this is some sort of logic you could do on the server instead, that would be much more ideal. Especially if this is gonna be used in a mobile app. You can update the cloud code without requiring an update to the mobile client. Coming up with a solution that keeps this logic in the cloud code would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Oh, I'm mostly just learning how to do some things with Cloud Code and wanted to see what its capabilities are. The current function that I was testing was just a function to return only the ObjectId's of items found with the query, rather than the objects themselves. Totally unnecessary, but you know... just seeing if it was possible :-)

Comment: What you want is query.includeKeys.  Does precisely what you're looking for. It will return only the keys you specify.  You can also do query.include to fetch a pointer to an object with the query, and that works with dot notation as well. `objectAQuery.include('objectB').include('objectB.objectC');`